# Server running 24/7 crashes router

Tags: windows, router

I have an unusual issue. I have a server with Windows 10 running 24/7, every 5-8 days it crashes my router in a way that shuts down the entire internet connection in the house through the router. The only way to solve the issue is to shut down the server and restart the router and when the connection returns can I turn the server back on.

- The server is being used as a .Net hosting server, i created DNS
  entries on unoeuro hosting website to point to my server. And in
  order to RDP my server, i access it using FTP port and in the router
  i re-route the FTP port to RDP port(Personal Reasons).
- I had a D-Link Router DIR-880L. I thought it was a cable issue,
  changed to a new cable(didn't help), tried new Ethernet Card and
  tried Wireless USB NetCard (didn't help either). So i thought it
  might be a Router issue.
- I bought a brand new Asus RT-AC88U(400$), same problem.

I am an IT-Engineer and i know my stuff, but now I am at a point where I am almost out of ideas.

Comment: Please further explain the state the router is in when it “crashed”: Does it respond to ping? Can you open the web interface? If so, what does it show? What about the status LEDs? What happens when you disable the FTP→RDP port forwarding? Try forwarding another port where NAT helpers are typically not involved, like port 22 (SSH) or port 443 (HTTPS).

Comment: Hi Daniel the router LED'es blink normaly except for the Internet one blinks red, with the old D-LINK router i could access it through cable only, with the new ASUS, i cannot the Web interface is down. i have'nt disabled port forwarding yet. It doesn't response to ping either.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the latest firmware on your router?

Comment: Hi Chris, yes i am, i updated the firmware to Asus'es latest firmware. didn't help either.

Comment: Is your server not closing connections correctly?

Comment: To be honest i do not know. I had a laptop before running as a server for a year with the same .net solutions hosted on it, no problem. 
Again if it was a bad Ethernet stick on the motherboard on this new server it would've been solved when i used a wireless usb dongle.

Comment: `netstat -o` should give you a list of all active connections. You may be exhausting the router's capability.

Comment: i did the netstat -o check before and nothing looked weird, i just did it again, the only foreign address is plex server even though i am not signed in to my plex account it is connected to plex server at amesterdam which is weird, but i highly doubt this is the issue.

Comment: I'd go with Daniel's suggestion next and see what happens when you do away with the FTP--> RDP forwarding rule in case it's getting confused and hosing up eventually with that rule. Also, check the router logs such as system logs and see what is logged just before and during the time and date the issue occurs. Start checking logs for specific indicators of issues logged at this level or undo special router configs and do the process of elimination type tasks if you've not already. Consider sniffing the data packets with Wireshark too and compare when it works and doesn't work more clues.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT.. An hour ago i rerouted the ports from ftp into HTTPS -> RDP. Unfortionatly the system log on the router doesn't show anything that might indicate a problem. I was in Berling between 16th of July until 20th of July, and it went down sometime between these two dates, when i checked thr routers System log, the last log was on July 14th!. So 3 weeks from now i will update this thread witht he result.

Comment: Since the problem affected two different routers and since the WAN (Internet) light is turning red, consider problems with your modem. next time, try resetting that first. But, most of all, I agree with the suggestion to get Wireshark involved and see what's actually going on.